# Infragistics XamDataChart - Column X Labels - half showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatachart

As you can clearly see the XAMDataChart is skipping putting the label on every other column.

I have no clue why this is happening. The code is the same for all of them and I have verified that the data is there.

[image]

Here is how they are generated

```
 CategoryXAxis catX = new CategoryXAxis();
 NumericYAxis numY = new NumericYAxis();
 foreach (var series in control.masterCollection)
 {                    
     catX.Name = "catX";                 
     catX.ItemsSource = series;
     catX.Label = "{Label}";
     catX.Gap = 20;

     numY.Name = "numY";


     ColumnSeries cs = new ColumnSeries()
     {                        
         ItemsSource = series,
         ValueMemberPath = "YPoint",
         XAxis = catX,
         YAxis = numY                        
     };

 }
```

Comment: Look in the [online documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v12.1~Infragistics.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart_members.html) page for your `XamDataChart`... there's probably just a property that you need to set to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is setting the Category X Axis objects interval to 1.

```
catX.Interval = 1;
```